# Image is not loading Instantly

Tags: java

In my code I want to load an icon on click of submit button but on the first click it is not visible but on the second click it is Visible
here is the code....

```
 Image logo=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("c.png");
 BufferedImage b=Temp.getClockBackGround();
 Graphics g=b.createGraphics();
```

These are the instance data members of my class and here is the action performed...

```
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eee){
try{

PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("alarmData.txt",true));
String s=(String)listPane1.getSelectedItem()+" "+(String)listPane2.getSelectedItem()+" "+(String)listPane3.getSelectedItem()+" "+(String)listPane4.getSelectedItem();
ps.print(s);
ps.println();
ps.close();
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

float ang=(Float.parseFloat(listPane2.getSelectedItem().toString())*30)+(float)(Float.parseFloat(listPane3.getSelectedItem().toString())*0.5);
System.out.println(ang);

g.drawImage(logo,l1.getX(95,ang)-10,l1.getY(95,ang)-10,null);
Temp.setClockBackGround(b);
}
}   
);
```

The Temp class is used to store the bufferedImage.
Here is the Temp class

```
    package Model;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class Temp{

    private  static BufferedImage background;

    public static void setClockBackGround(BufferedImage bg){
    background=bg;
    }
    public static BufferedImage getClockBackGround(){
    BufferedImage b=background;

    return b;
    }
    }
```

here is the image   [the clock image is the main image on that a small logo of Alarm is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAtCZ.jpg)

Comment: Exactly why do you assume that image does not load? Note that in the current code all that is visible is that you load the image, draw it to another one, and store the result in a variable - there is no trace of how and why it should get displayed. In fact you are set-ting back the variable to the same BufferedImage object, which you were get-ting at the beginning.

Comment: You mean first i need to change graphics to buffered image and then assigning it to variable b but the real thing is if the same buffered image is set in temp why it is changing on the second click? and to check here i used this buffered Image variable b before i was directly converting the returned image in graphics and drawing the image my concern is either it should not change at all or why it is showing the logo on the second click

Comment: Re-assigning the variable to its current content was just a side remark. The main thing is that this code you have posted here does not draw anything on the screen, and thus it is not possible to tell what happens in your other code where you would actually draw something - how ```Temp.background``` is supposed to reach the screen. Practically you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post a more complete code, preferably still something short.

Comment: Toolkit.getImage loads an Image in the background.  You’re probably using the Image object before it has been fully loaded.  You can specify a non-null ImageObserver argument in your call to Graphics.draw to account for this, but the easier solution is to load your image using `ImageIO.read(new File("c.png"))`, which will read the entire image before returning.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ImageIcon instead of Image and you can use it on a label, to load that image

for ex:-
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("c.png");

hope this will help...

Comment: the real problem is why it is not loading the first time and after first click it is loading the icon on the desired location.so there is no need to use Imageicon please read the complete post.